# Finding Sqllite database in Android studio 3.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I'm new at Android development ,I have created a login xml with an sqllite database in andriod version 3.2  but  could not locate the database ,I have searched the internet  all i could see was andriod device monitor but it was removed from version 3.2   can someone help me in locating my  database

Comment: I believe it's now **Device Explorer**, and is typically at bottom right of the the main window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Device Monitor was deprecated in Android Studion 3.1 and replaced in Android 3.2.

As per  [https://developer.android.com/studio/releases](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#device-monitor-command) and

[Android Device Monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html)

It's replacement is [**Device File Explorer**](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer.html), which is made available as a button, with the name Device File Explorer, typically/initially at the bottom right *(it is movable)* or via View/Tool Windows/Device File Explorer e.g. :-

[image]